# PyGtk3 how to change application theme?

Tags: pygtk

i tried rc_parse method using Gtk.rc_parse("path/to/Hooli/gtk-3/gtk.css") code but it is not working. this question is simlpy but solution of question not easy. how can i change the my gtk apllication theme ? or how can i use custom theme on my gtk application ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk

settings = gtk.Settings.get_default()
settings.set_property("gtk-theme-name", "Numix")
settings.set_property("gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme", False)  # if you want use dark theme, set second arg to True

# getting all existing properties #

for i in settings.list_properties():
    print(i)
```

this codes working very correctly on windows, linux, ... i hope this solve your problem

Comment: removing `settings.set_property("gtk-theme-name", "Numix")` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the old way with the new CSS way.

I wrote a few examples that are in the demos folder of the pygobject tree, the most simple one is this one:

https://git.gnome.org/browse/pygobject/tree/demos/gtk-demo/demos/Css/css_accordion.py

In short you have to prepare the css:

https://git.gnome.org/browse/pygobject/tree/demos/gtk-demo/demos/data/css_accordion.css

The file is loaded into a Gtk.CssProvider()

```
    provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
    provider.load_from_data(bytes.get_data())
```

Which is loaded by the function apply_css()

```
def apply_css(self, widget, provider):
    Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider(widget.get_style_context(),
                                  provider,
                                  Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)

    if isinstance(widget, Gtk.Container):
        widget.forall(self.apply_css, provider)
```

Run the full example to get a better idea of how it works.

Comment: i tried it but it isn't working. i used provider.load_from_path("/home/user/.themes/Hooli/gtk.css") code but my window theme not changed and program gave too many errors, i want use Hooli gtk3 theme on my app without default theme. can you give me an example? Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid you are trying the impossible, get a theme developed for the whole system and apply it to a specific app, yo might have to cut it down to only what you need, rename it and put it in your application folder

Comment: my system theme adwaita but  i want apply numix theme on my gtk app without changing my system default theme. Isn't there a way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe Matthias Clasen can come to the rescue https://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/2014/05/06/tweaking-a-the-gtk-theme-using-css/